# How to SetCookie() in a System.Net.HttpWebRequest request for another Page2.aspx？

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

How can I SetCookie in Page1.aspx by a System.Net.HttpWebRequest request for Page2.aspx which handle the SetCookie() function？

Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx are in the same webapp.

Page1.aspx：

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost/Page2.aspx";
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest myReq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            System.Net.HttpWebResponse HttpWResp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream myStream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream();
        }
```

Page2.aspx：

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string userName = "Lily";
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true); 
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to send the cookie back to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx).

However, if you're just trying to send the auth cookie back to the client, you should move the Page2 code to a static function, and call the function from both pages.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, you should be able to iterate through HttpWResp.Headers() until you get the one with a "Set-Cookie" key, then parse that string, then set another cookie in your Page1.aspx code.